# Cannot upload images on Magento 2.3.0 in Xampp

Tags: image-upload, magento2.3.0, xampp

I have freshly installed **Magento 2.3.0** successfully in **Xampp**. After installing, I have tried to upload logo image but couldn't and it says as in the below image

[image]

What could be the problem and why am I not able to upload an image?

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: try to redeploy static view files for admin area then run the indexer command

Comment: @magefms I have redeployed the static content but still can't upload an image.

Comment: also run indexer command ?

Comment: make sure folders for pub is not set as read only

Comment: I have done all the steps, redeployed the static files, reindexed the indexers but still couldn't able to upload the image.

Comment: @Siva, Were you able to solve the above problem?

Comment: @MohitKumarArora No, the problem is still there. I have tried all the possible solution but not working for me. Can you please guide me with this?